# Find Specific Values in a Dataframe and Record the (Row, Column) Index Pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a Pandas data frame that looks like the following:

[image]

Now, I want to go through the entire data frame and record the column and row index pairs (shown as just numbers for this example) for any value that is less than 0.12. For example, I want to identify 0.105263, record that value, and record that it is located in row 4, column 2. Are there any efficient methods for traversing a data frame and storing this kind of data in a new data frame?

My goal is to have the output look like the following:

```
Row  Col  Value
==================
4     2   0.105263
...
```

Comment: What's your expected output? How is the new dataframe looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```py
out = (df[df.le(0.12)]
       .stack().reset_index()
       .rename(columns={'level_0':'row', 'level_1':'col', 0: 'val'}))
```

Comment: numpy nonzero might be a faster option